# Citing another author’s summary of other works in a journal article

Tags: citations, writing

I want to use the information from this block of text talking about psychoanalysis:

> Some authors (e.g. Allison et al., 2006 and Turkle, 1995) compare the player and avatar's relationship to a transmission field, as roughly defined by psychoanalysis: the avatar is not in exclusive competence of the player, while not being completely separated from them. It lies somewhere near the boarder of external and internal (psychological) reality.

I am unsure how to put it in my paper. Do I still say that the information is from the article I'm reading it from, or would I mention the authors of that information? Something like:

> Lukas Blinka in his article entitled "The relationship of players to their avatars in MMORPGs" compares the relation of a player to their avatar to that of a transmission field...

The relevant style guide is [MLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_MLA_Style_Manual).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is write it so that the author of article is clearly identified as the compiler, rather than the originator, of the idea. For example:

> Lukas Blinka notes that some critics have “compared the player and avatar’s relationship to a transmission field” (##).

You would only include Blinka's article in your bibliography. If I cared to know who those critics were, I'd go to his article to find them.